# Maximum or minimum value of trigonometric equation?

Tags: trigonometry

How to find maximum values of trigonometric equations like $\sin^4 x + \sin 4x$?

Is there any model or method? or we have to use maxima minima algorithm, AM-GM inequality and graphical representation?

Comment: What do you mean by maximum value of an equation?

Comment: sorry, its my mistake it should be of form y = f(x) not f(x) = 0

Comment: Recall that -1 <= sin(x) <= 1 is true for all x. Use some algebra to work your way to the expression you want. Do this for each term. Then you should be able to find the max/min of your entire function

Comment: @user146551 We get here very ugly numbers.